# How to use pre-defined destroy method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I wonder about the best practice way of deleting an object made from a model?
I have seen several similar questions but no one touching on the whole subject nor my specifics further down.

I want to create a delete-button deleting a specific object in laravel. I know how to do this but am afraid I am over complicating things.

Let say I have a model named Post

I also have the controller PostController. When I made this controller I resourced it. Thanks to that I have several methods prepared eg. destroy

```
 /**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Post  $post
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    //
}
```

I am getting a bit confused as if to why it gives me the type hint **Post** and also the $post parameter? For me it would make sense if it took $id as a parameter.

BUT again and again, I am not Tay-Tay. So every time something does not make sense to me I think that I just missed something. SO, with risk of being to broad how do I make the a delete button that uses the pre-defined destroy method? am looking for an answer on these three steps:

1. HTML (How to make the form / button)
2. web.php (the route)
3. PostController (how do I execute the destroy? I know how to do it with the id but with the whole object as a parameter? How is that even sent in the first place? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have done it that way is just to be more sensible.
Like keep up with `Object Oriented`

And don't worry. even though it has `destroy(Post $post)`, you don't have to provide a `Post` object to that `destroy()` function. You have only to pass the `id` of the post through the `request`. the rest handles by Laravel.

Laravel looks for a post in the post table which has an id that you pass in the request, and fetch that post object and provide it to the `destroy()` function.

You just have to call `delete()` on it.

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    // laravel has found the post for you.
    $post->delete();
}
```

Lets take a look at your approach.
You can change it to `destroy($id)`

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // you have to find the particular post from database to delete.
    Post::where('id', $id)->delete();
}
```

See, its more complicated.

### So to answer your 3 questions.

**Form**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('post.destroy'), 1 }}">
    <!-- here the '1' is the id of the post which you want to delete -->

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();
}
```

Comment: better to use `Post::find($id)->delete();` instead of `Post::where('id', $id)->delete();`

Comment: No it's not better, because find($id) will fetch the result from database. It's un-necessary overhead. you don't have to fetch the row, only if you want to delete it.

Comment: yes, you are right, just woke up :))) firstly I was looking only to where part, and when I finished my comment I have added ->delete() :D

Comment: thank you for this answer @TharakaDilshan - I think it is really help full and I hope more will be helped by it. however out of a pedagogic point of view I should have used another model-name than post as that can be mixed up with the http methodes. Could you change it to lets say 'Comment' - then I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

From the official Laravel docs:

> Since we have bound all {user} parameters to the App\User model, a
>   User instance will be injected into the route. So, for example, a
>   request to profile/1 will inject the User instance from the database
>   which has an ID of 1.
>
> If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP
>   response will be automatically generated.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#explicit-binding

Answer (score -1):

pass one more parameter id in your destroy method

public function destroy($id,Post $post){

$post= $post->findOrFail($id);

if (!$post->delete()) {

```
 return Redirect::back()->withErrors($post->errors());
```

}

Flash::success(self::DELETE_MESSAGE);
 return Redirect::back();

}

Comment: you don't need to use both id and Post, $post variably will automatically find Post object by passed to it post_id